# How to built in-app purchase in iOS with device iPad version 5.1.1

Tags: ios5

I've built project in-app purchase with iOS device version 5.1 successfully.

But on iOS device version 5.1.1 it's not working. It shows an alert message stating that the product is not available in app store.

How can I solve this problem? Please, explain me.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us some relevant code please?